# Subsetting a string based on pre- and suffix

Tags: regex, r, subset

I have a column with these type of names:

```
sp_O00168_PLM_HUMAM   
sp_Q8N1D5_CA158_HUMAN  
sp_Q15818_NPTX1_HUMAN  
tr_Q6FGH5_Q6FGH5_HUMAN  
sp_Q9UJ99_CAD22_HUMAN
```

I want to remove everything before, and including, the second _ and everything after, and including, the third _.

I do not which to remove based on number of characters, since this is not a fixed number.

The output should be:

```
PLM  
CA158    
NPTX1  
Q6FGH5  
CAD22
```

I have played around with these, but don't quite get it right..
library(stringer)
str_sub(x,-6,-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> gsub(".*_.*_(.*)_.*", "\\1", "sp_O00168_PLM_HUMAM") 
[1] "PLM"
```

Comment: Thank you! My final code is: test <- gsub(".*_.*_(.*)_.*", "\\1", x$names). This is the vector a want.

Answer (score 2):

That’s not really a subset in programming terminology<sup>1</sup>, it’s a *substring*. In order to extract partial strings, you’d usually use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) (pretty much regardless of language); in R, [this is accessible via `sub` and other related functions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html):

```
pattern = '^.*_.*_([^_]*)_.*$'
result = sub(pattern, '\\1', strings)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Aside: taking a subset is, as the name says, a *set* operation, and sets are defined by having no duplicate elements and there’s no particular order to the elements. A string by contrast is a *sequence* which is a very different concept.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible regular expression is this:

```
sub("^(?:.+_){2}(.+?)_.+", "\\1", vec)
# [1] "PLM"    "CA158"  "NPTX1"  "Q6FGH5" "CAD22"
```

where `vec` is your vector of strings.

A visual explanation:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Impressive! Thank you.