# Subset not based on exact match, but partial in R

Tags: regex, r, substring

This is a follow-up question from here:
[Subsetting a string based on pre- and suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407361/subsetting-a-string-based-on-pre-and-suffix)

When you have this command:

```
    d <- subset(b, b$X %in% test)
```

This command look for all in `b$X` that exactly matches test. How can I manipulate it to say its enough that the values in `b$X` contains `test`?
I.e. if `b$X` has a value `"something"` and `test` has `"thing"`. Then I would regard this as a match.

Important update! Test has 512 values, not only 1 as in the example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can replace `%in%` with `grepl`:

```
# examples
x <- c("thing", "something", "some", "else")
test <- c("thing", "some")

# exact match
x %in% test
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

# substring match (regex)
pattern <- paste(test, collapse = "|") # create regex pattern
grepl(pattern, x)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

The whole command for your task:

```
d <- subset(b, grepl(paste(test, collapse= "|"), b$X))
```

The `"|"` means logical *or* in regular expressions.

Comment: I may have miss-leaded you. test has 512 different values. I guess that why I get "argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" ?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm. But I still can't find all my 512 names, only 287. With exact test I found only 256. Its nothing wrong with the codes, it must be something else...

Comment: a little late here to help you @user3236594, but the problem may be with order. The `grepl(paste(test, collapse= "|")` matches either thingsome or thing or some or something but not, "thing blah some". You need to do `grepl(thing, b$x) & grepl(some, b$x)` to make it work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

No need for b$ in subset.

```
d <- subset(b, grepl(paste(test, collapse= "|"), X))
```

Comment: It may be helpful to explain what you have changed from the original code, and why. This will make your answer more useful to future visitors.